# Отследить открытие файла по интернет

Tags: excel

Здравствуйте. Есть вопрос по поводу как возможно отследить обращение к файлу xls, после его скачивания из интернета. Думал прикрепить ссылку на картинку из сайта, чтоб при открытии автоматом грузилась картинка в файл, но не получилось. Подскажите, как можно это сделать?

Comment: В общем случае — никак. Представьте себе, что файл был закачан, скопирован на дискету и открыт на компьютере без доступа и интернету.

Comment: Скажите, какова общая задача, может можно решить другими способами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Копайте в сторону:

1. Вставка
2. Сводная таблица
3. Использовать внешний источник данных
4. Выбрать подключение
5. Найти другие
6. Новое подключение к SQL-серверу [или другой тип подключения]
7. [настройте подключение]
8. Контекстное меню сводной таблицы - Параметры сводной таблицы
9. Вкладка данные
10. Обновить при открытии файла
11. Прячете сводную таблицу на отдельном листе, называете его "служебный"
12. Скрываете служебный лист из его контекстного меню
13. Смотрите лог обращений к SQL-серверу от введенного пользователя

Этот способ не будет требовать никаких подтверждающих действий от пользователя.

Comment: А на клиенте (в офисной программе) можно отключить лазание во "внешние источники" без спросу? А то потенциальная дыра типа infrastructure disclosure получается же.

Comment: 2ReinRaus спасибо, я в принципе там уже и начал копать, но пока что то не получается. Но однозначно этот вариант лучший.